# I have a problem about array based on char

Tags: arrays, string, char, output

I am troubling to understand the output of following program.:------

Here is a char array and i put the value 1 only.
but whay is show's the full name rather then only one character.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char name[1];

cout<<"enter name"<<endl;

cin>>name;
cout<<"your entered name is :--"<<endl;
cout<<name;
return 0;
}
```

instead of it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char name[15];

cout<<"enter name"<<endl;

cin>>name[15];
cout<<"your entered name is :--"<<endl;
cout<<name[15];
return 0;
}
```

when i do this then it is show me only one character.